# problem with the display about the dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

I want to create a dashboard in R.  But I don't understand where I can see this.

On the net I see a lot of code to create "beautiful" dashboards but when I try it, I can't see the dashboard and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/get_started.html) page.

Comment: You need to run the app if you aren't doing that already. Look at the function `runApp()`

Comment: Hmm  yes but if I want create a dashboard since my data.  For example If I have a data who give me the mean, the var ... and I want put this in my dashboard.  I created a new sheet in R (ui.R)  but can I use data from my other sheet ??

Comment: You can use data defined in `global.R`, and pass that to reactive expressions in `server.R` if it needs to be filtered or otherwise manipulated based on inputs. But it sounds like it would help you to look at the link Carlos provided, and/or do a short course on Shiny, as it will be hard to progress without a more fundamental understanding of what is going on.